# StrongSwan compiled for Android Kernel root

Tags: android, arm

How to compile or cross-compile StrongSwan (VPN) for the Android Kernel. I'm not talking about the .APK but the c++ binaries from the source code.

I read the [official documentation](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/InstallationDocumentation) which talks about compiling StrongSwan for compiling strongswan in general. I also read the [official documentation](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/android) for cross-compiling strongswan for Android.

I tested both methods without success:

1. First method, I tried cross-compiling with the NDK for arm from my Ubuntu, but at the ./configure step, I have of gmp library an error which I couldn't resolve.

   `configure: error: GNU Multi Precision library gmp not found`

I tried with various versions of strongswan and Android API

2. Second method, I emulates a raspberry pi with QEMU (ARM64) and inside I could compile strongswan and run it. But the problem when I put it on the Android Studio emulator, I get an error. I think it is due to the fact that I compiled strongswan with dynamic libs. I tried with the option

   `--disable-shared --enable-static --enable-monolithic`

But when I do the command file on binaries:

```
    # file starter

starter: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=e8e45d6d999bee049625c8c28e3552248045a2ab, with debug_info, not stripped
```

The binaries seem to be dynamically linked. How could I compile them statically?

Comment: Android is based on linux but you need `su` to run c++ binaries. Provided documentation guides how to make native library to use with android application not standalone.

Comment: @StanislavBondar thank you for your answer. Yes! That's why I said Kernel root on my title. Could you give more details for I can understand better the way that I should take?